# SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function isIE () {
    var myNav = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    return (myNav.indexOf('msie') != -1) ? parseInt(myNav.split('msie')[1]) : false;
}

window.isIEOld = isIE() && isIE() < 9;
window.isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i);

var img = $('.video').data('placeholder'),
    video = $('.video').data('video'),
    noVideo = $('.video').data('src'),
    el = '';

if($(window).width() > 599 && !isIEOld && !isiPad) {
    el +=   '<video autoplay loop poster="' + img + '">';
    el +=       '<source src="' + video + '" type="video/mp4">';
    el +=   '</video>';
} else {
    el = '<div class="video-element" style="background-image: url(' + noVideo + ')"></div>';
}

$('.video').prepend(el);
</script>
```

I'm getting this js error but can't figure out why... it doesn't reference a line number. I'm enqueuing the script in Wordpress functions.php...

Answer (score 3):

Your script tag is not right:

```
<script type="text/html">
```

should defintely be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: thx.. i pasted an earlier version i was experimenting on.

the correct script is here: http://beatriceandwoodsley.com/2016/wp-content/themes/padre-child/js/custom-script.js?ver=4.3.1